# one-to-many SQLite relationship query

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

have an sqlite database that holds many cities, each city has a month and each month has 30 days. i created this database using CoreData when i was developing iOS apps on Xcode. now i want to retrieve the days that belongs to a specific month and that month belongs to a specific city.

Database map from Xcode :

[image]

Database structure :

[image]

Any one knows how accomplish this ? thanks

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Also, any query you have attempted is also helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [SQLiteQueryBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html) class.
You can set (and join) the tables using the [setTables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#setTables(java.lang.String)) method.

> Sets the list of tables to query. Multiple tables can be specified to perform a join. For example: setTables("foo, bar") setTables("foo LEFT OUTER JOIN bar ON (foo.id = bar.foo_id)")

Parameters
inTables    the list of tables to query on